# No valid Prisma config could be loaded

Tags: prisma

**Describe the bug**
I just enabled single replica set for mongodb. to be able to track the oplog.
every things work fine when there is not replica set enalbed.
I enabled the single node replica set just to be able to capture the oplog

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      prisma_config: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var prisma_management_api_secret=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementapisecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mongo
            uri: 'mongodb://user:pass@mongo:27017/?connect=direct'
  mongo:
    # image: mongo:3.6
    image: mongo:4.2.1
    restart: always
    hostname: mongodb
    # ports:
    # - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME: rp0
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - /Users/initdb.d/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - /Users/mongo-logs/:/var/log/mongodb/
      - mongo:/data/db
      - /Users/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
      - ~/desktop/mongo-backup/backup-20201019220001:/dump
      # - /opt/mongo-backups:/backups
    healthcheck:
      test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate().ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo -u $${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME} -p $${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD} --quiet) -eq 1
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 30s
    command: ["-f", "/etc/mongod.conf", "--replSet", "$${MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME}", "--bind_ip_all"]
volumes:
  mongo:
  mongo-conf:
# networks:
#   elastic:
```

**error trace**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: java.lang.RuntimeException: No valid Prisma config could be loaded.
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:26)
        at com.prisma.config.ConfigLoader$.load(ConfigLoader.scala:40)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalDependencies.<init>(PrismaLocalDependencies.scala:48)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.delayedEndpoint$com$prisma$local$PrismaLocalMain$1(PrismaLocalMain.scala:13)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$delayedInit$body.apply(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
        at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain$.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala:8)
        at com.prisma.local.PrismaLocalMain.main(PrismaLocalMain.scala
```

Comment: OK fixed.
just a case typo in prisma_config => PRISMA_CONFIG

Comment: try this for your query: `db.<replaceCollection>.find({static:{   $elemMatch: {     "variant.attributes":{       $elemMatch:{ value:"a"}       }     }   } })`